# How to make an And-Or tree using Angular2 and Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, tree

How do you create an AND-OR Tree view using Angular2 and Typescript? 
I am basically trying to come up with an and-or tree structure and also be able to do basic functions. New to Angular2. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Can you reformulate ?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to create an And-Or tree-view using Angular2 and Typescript.

Comment: What is an And-or tree-view?

Comment: An and/or tree starts with an OR top node that may have as children AND nodes. Then an AND node may have as children OR nodes. And so on.